# Trying to convert a UNIX time in c# into DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have tried some other solutions from here but none have worked. My current method is trying to use the TimeSpan method:

unixtime is an int, contains '1502557200'

```
var test_date = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(unixtime);
```

test_date became '{17390.17:00:00}'

What am I doing wrong? I was trying to avoid creating a method to handle the conversion, and just trying to do it inline,

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unix Epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC<sup>1</sup>.

But the .NET zero time is slightly earlier. So you covert as an offset from the Unix Epoch:

```
var dt = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).AddSeconds(unixTime);
```

This is simpler in .NET Core and .NET 5.0 (and later) with the addition of the field [`DateTime.UnixEpoch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.datetime.unixepoch?view=net-5.0):

```
var dt = DateIMe.UnixEpock.AddSeconds(unixTime);
```

There is also [`DateTimeOffset.UnixEpoch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.unixepoch?view=net-5.0).

<sup>1</sup> Was defined later than this, so "what UTC would have been if it had existed".

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Indeed :-) (Same issue each new year: keep writing last year's number.)

Comment: Thanks Richard, worked for me